# How to form the hql body which returns int value?

Tags: hibernate

I have this hql statement which I want to return an int value.

```
String hql = "Select FlagCount from Tourism_Question_Attributes_Table where tourismQuestions.questionId = :questionId";
```

How to do it ?

Comment: And your problem is?

Comment: how to execute this statement so that it returns an int value (FlagCount)

Answer (score 0):

wellit depends if you are using jpa, spring jsf or just java

if you are using jpa and spring use this one
using hql :
    List list = new Arraylist;
    list = (List) this.getHibernateTemplate().find(hql);

and it depends if you are using jpa

if you are ony using java :use this

```
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;

Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

Query query = session.createQuery("select and so on..");
// set parameter values, e.g.
// query.setString("name", "Matthias");
List result = query.list();

tx.commit();
session.close();
```

Comment: I am new to all of this. In my application i am using spring mvc and hibernate and yes i dont want it to return a list

Comment: what is your return type?

Comment: @Override
 public int findFlagCount(long questionId) {
  String hql = "Select FlagCount from Tourism_Question_Attributes_Table where tourismQuestions.questionId = :questionId";
   Query query =  getSession().createQuery(hql)
     .setParameter("questionId", questionId);
  
   return  (int) query.uniqueResult();
 }

Comment: This is what i am doing